# Do modifiers work in interfaces

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, compiler

Can an interface enforce a modifier on a function?

For example, does this work:

```
contract TokenSeller {

  modifer enforceSale(uint256 amount) {
    ERC20 t = token();
    uint256 beforeBalance = t.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    _;
    uint256 afterBalance = t.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    require(afterBalance == beforeBalance + amount);
  }

  function buyToken(uint256 amount) public enforceSale(amount) returns(uint256);

  function token() public returns(ERC20);
}
```

Is there another way to achieve this kind of interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### SHORT ANSWER

No, maybe with abstract contracts you can achieve something similar

### LONG ANSWER

First of all to create an interface the keyword `interface` should be used (I used version 0.4.24 of solidity and [the solidity documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/solidity/latest/solidity.pdf). 
I played a little bit with your code and when you try to create a function in an interface with a modifier, like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface A {
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(getOwner() == msg.sender);
        _;
    }
    function getOwner() public returns(address);
    function updateState() public onlyOwner();
 }
```

You'd receive this **warning**: 
[image]

Therefore, apparently, you cannot enforce a modifier in an interface.

Maybe you can try with an abstract contract and [the template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
contract A {

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(getOwner() == msg.sender);
        _;
    }
    // The internal keyword let function be visible only to the contract itself and the derivatives
    function getOwner() internal returns(address);  

    function performOperation() internal; // The real operation

    function updateState() public onlyOwner() {
        performOperation();
    }

}
```

So when you create a concrete subcontract can specify the "`performOperation`" function:

```
contract B is A {
    address private owner;
    uint state;
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        state = 0;
    }
    function getOwner() internal returns(address) {
        return owner;
    }
    function performOperation() internal {
        state = state + 1;
    }
}
```

Obviously with abstract classes you can also avoid the function getOwner in this way:

```
    contract A {
        address internal owner;

        constructor() internal {
           owner = msg.sender;
        }
        modifier onlyOwner() {
            require(owner == msg.sender);
            _;
        }
        function performOperation() internal;
        function updateState() public onlyOwner() {
            performOperation();
        }
    }
```

and so you can instantiate a subcontract with already the owner variable :

```
contract B is A {
    uint state;
    //Call A's constructor before B's one
    constructor() A() public { state = 0; }
    function performOperation() internal { state = state + 1; }
}
```

P.S. Did you try your code on remix https://remix.ethereum.org ?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use a virtual contract as an "interface" (as suggested above). The scheme is:

```
abstract contract A {
    modifier adminOnly {
    /// checks admin
    _;
    }
    function f() external adminOnly returns (uint){
      return __f__(); 
    }
    function __f__() virtual internal returns (uint);
}

contract B is A {
     function __f__() internal override returns (uint) {
     // whatever you do here has modifier applied before
     }
}
```

and now you can only override `__f__` is subsequent contract that would inherit from A and thus you enforce the modifier